# jQuery event not firing until second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

I have the following jQuery code. The first time I click a link, nothing happens; however, upon clicking the link the second time, the expected action occurs.

```
$("a[rel]").bind("click", function(){
   $(".close_button_change_password").attr('id','change_password_'+$(this).attr('id'));
   $(this).overlay({
      // disable this for modal dialog-type of overlays
      closeOnClick: true,
      mask: {
         color: '#fff',
         loadSpeed: 200,
         opacity: 0.8
      }
   });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="#change_password" id="1">change password</a>
```

Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this problem? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What's the problem? Could it be that you're only initiating the overlay on click?

Comment: After a first look: **!important!** you cannot give `ID`'s numeric values! like : `id="1"` Use a letter for the first character: `id="a1"`

Comment: @roXon - I'm pretty sure you can. Javascript variables can't start with numbers, but the id is an HTML attribute.

Comment: @roXon: in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) you can.

Comment: @user828584 According to the HTML 4.01 spec you cannot begin an `id` attribute with a digit. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Comment: @user828584 in HTML < 5 an `id` starting with a non-alphabetic character is invalid

Comment: I don't get why this works then? http://jsfiddle.net/6F7mJ/

Comment: change id="cp1" didnt repair my problem ;(

Comment: @user828584 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: We did'nt say it will. Just discussing the 'ID' validations.

Comment: So : if you are using XHTML = don't use numbers for you first ID character! @user828584

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/6F7mJ/1/ Now ask us why it is not good (look at the CSS)

Comment: I had the same thing with an old overlay jQuery plugin. It _was_  working but was actually showing the overlay and then hiding it immediately again. Which overlay plugin are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("a[rel]").live("click", function(){ ....
```

or you could try.., but I dont think this would solve it.

```
$("a[rel]").live("change", function(){ ....
```

And make sure its in DOM ready.

---

You could try and prevent the default action, maybe this is interfering with your first click.

```
$("a[rel]").bind("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault(); // <---------^^
$(".close_button_change_password").attr('id','change_password_'+$(this).attr('id'));
$(this).overlay({
   // disable this for modal dialog-type of overlays
   closeOnClick: true,
   mask: {
      color: '#fff',
      loadSpeed: 200,
      opacity: 0.8
   }
    });
});
```

Comment: live didnt repair my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, embed your code with $(document).ready({}) statement. It makes sure you'r dom will be affected with code only after all html syntax is parsed by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("a[rel]").click(function(){alert($(this).attr("id"));});
```

to see if there is something wrong with your HTML code. then you can add other statement in order to debug your js code

Answer (score 0):

From : http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html

`// select one or more elements to be overlay triggers`

Setting the overlay to the click attribute of HTML might be redundant. Based on the above, I would assume that the overlay is already activated on click.